# jQuery $().each vs $.each() vs for loop

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, each

I'm new to JS and Query so I think it's a very simple task, I would like just for a test rewrite **"loop"** from **$.each()** to **$().each()** and for loop.
This is my code.

```
var tab = ["John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian"],
    $list = $('#list');

$.each(tab,function(index,value){
    $list.append("<li>"+ value+ "</li>");
});
```

Second and third loops don't work:

```
tab.each(function(index){
    $list.append("<li>"+ tab[index] + "</li>");
});
```

and

```
for (var i,len=tab.length;i<len;i++) {
    $list.append("<li>"+ tab[i]+ "</li>");
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: There isn't a difference. Is there any?

Comment: variable i is not initialized in for loop.

Comment: And there is a difference with regard to $.each and $(..).each(), in the first case, jQuery expects the first argument to be an array and will execute the callback for each element in the array. For the second, jQuery will select elements within the document that match the criteria specified and then will iterate over each of the matched elements.  If there are no elements (which there most likely aren't, because you're trying to add them), no action will be taken in the .each() operation as specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error in correct initialization of `for` loop:

```
for (var i,len=tab.length;i<len;i++) {
//-------^ - Missing inital value.
    $list.append("<li>"+ tab[i]+ "</li>");
}
```

Change to:

```
for (var i=0,len=tab.length;i<len;i++) {
    $list.append("<li>"+ tab[i]+ "</li>");
}
```

Second one doesn't work because, `tab` is not a jQuery object to iterate! `:)` The syntax of `$.each` is either:

```
$.each(dataArray, function() { });
```

Or, if you have a DOM jQuery object:

```
$(Selector).each(dataArray, function() { });
```

Comment: Yes you right! "$(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object."

Comment: 2 small points. Not initializing i is not a syntax error. It is perfectly valid syntax, but it yields unexpected results. It is also important to know why the uninitialized i is giving the unexpected result: (undefined < 5) === false

Comment: @bstakes Updated answer accordingly. `:)`

Comment: your code samples provide better context than my explanations alone, you've got my up vote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change as `var i=0, len=tab.length`  in

```
for (var i,len=tab.length;i<len;i++) {
    $list.append("<li>"+ tab[i]+ "</li>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are iterating over a Javascript array, not a jQuery selection, you have to use $.each, that is the way that it works.

As for your third example, i needs to be initialized with 0. Otherwise it is undefined which is always false when comparing to the length of the array.

Comment: Since kuba0506 calls himself a JS beginner, you helped him more with a corrected example and explanatory knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.)

Also [see here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/):

Here's what you need to remember:

- Methods called on jQuery selections are in the $.fn namespace, and automatically receive and return the selection as this.
- Methods in the $ namespace are generally utility-type methods, and do not work with selections; they are not automatically passed any arguments, and their return value will vary.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your JS array to become a jQuery object for beeing able to call each on it:

```
$(tab).each(function(){
  $list.append("<li>"+ this + "</li>")
})
```

and initialize your running variable with zero (i=0), furthermore for readability reasons you should not store the tab.length into a temporary variable:

```
for(var i=0; i<tab.length; i++) {
  $list.append("<li>"+ tab[i]+ "</li>") 
}
```

Comment: tab is not a jQuery collection, so that will not work.

Comment: Wrapping tab with $() is generating a jQuery object for iterating with each().

Comment: ok, that looks better. not the best way to go about it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var tab = ["John", "Steve", "Ben", "Damon", "Ian"];
    for(i=0;i<=tab.length;i++)
    {
        alert(tab[i]);
    }
```